# Why can't I login to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I've used MySQL for years so I might be naively layering my MySQL expectations on to Posgres, but I am hitting a wall. I created a user, `flasktut` with `LOGIN CREATEDB` but when I try to log in, I get 
`psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "flasktut"` -- I tried resetting the password:

```
postgres=# ALTER USER flasktut WITH PASSWORD 'zx80xb1';
ALTER ROLE
```

and I'm still seeing the error. I suspect I'm doing something super obvious wrong here?

Comment: When you create one user you have to give him permision to one db, and then when user try to login he has to specify what db he is trying to access. Unless he is a superuser. How you create the user?

Comment: _Peer authentication_ happens without a password.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html and adapt your configuration to the security policy that best fits your needs.

Comment: How are you connecting to the server? Write the psql command you run. Is the server running on your local machine or a remote one? If it is on localhost, are you connecting by domain socket or IP? Look at the pg_hba.conf file. All the login schemes and their authentication methods are listed there.

Comment: On my local machine I usually create a username same as my loginname (on os x, FreeBSD/Linux slightly different pg-username) with "PGUSER=postgres createuser -d claus" where -d gives me permission to create a database with "createdb my-db". Then "psql my-db".

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer to your question is that there are two parts to logging in, to a Postgres database, and you're considering only one.

Logging into Postgres, has two parts:

1. The outer security check ensures that certain IP addresses / subnets / local or foreign hosts can be (dis)allowed to even 'reach' the Postgres database. The second aspect to that is that a given combination of user / database is allowed to go through. Importantly, your current setup is probably missing this aspect, and although you've seemingly taken care of the point 2 (below), it doesn't matter, because the login attempts aren't even reaching step 2.
2. Once the login process gets through the outer check, the Database / User itself should be valid / existing and usable.

The first aspect (above) is controlled by the [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, and what you need to ensure is that when the database parses through the pg_hba.conf file, the 'first' line that is permissive enough to apply to a given login scenario, is what is accepted as the effective 'rule' for that login attempt.

For e.g.

If logging in locally (without `127.0.0.1` or `eth0` etc. IP addresses)

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Should allow *any* login process to get through. Once you're able to login, try to restrict and make things more secure (since the above would allow every attempt to go through).

Importantly, subsequent lines although may be more secure / apt they wouldn't apply if a previous line in the configuration file already is considered as a candidate for a login attempt. Also, don't forget to restart / reload Postgres after *each* change to `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to localhost on machines that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

So edit the pg_hba.conf file and add/update the lines:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Now run `psql -d <your_db> -U flasktut`

No password should be asked since we set the method to 'trust' and you should be logged in.

When you feel confident with your postgres skills, you should probably change the 'trust' above to something safer, like 'md5'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider here.

First, the [settings in `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) need to allow you to connect to whatever database you are trying to connect to. A typical entry in the file looks like this:

```
host       my_db   myself  192.168.1.17/32  md5
host       all     all     192.168.1.0/24   md5
```

The first line allows a specific user (`myself`) from a specific remote client (`192.168.1.17/32`) to connect to a specific database (`my_db`) over TCP/IP (`host`). The second line allows any user to connect to any database on the network `192.168.1.0/24`, typical network address for home or a small office. Both need to authenticate with a password (`md5`). You should add a line like either of the above to allow `flasktut` to even reach the server for establishing a connection. Note that when you change this file you need to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

The second issue is that your new user `flasktut` needs to have the permission to connect to whatever database s/he wants to connect to:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE some_db TO flasktut;
```

And then within that database you have to grant privileges to access the objects, either directly or by granting role `flasktut` membership in a group role that has the required permissions:

```
GRANT some_role TO flasktut;
```

If `flasktut` is going to have her/his own database, you are probably better off as a superuser impersonating user `flasktut` to create the database and then letting the real user log in to that database her/himself:

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION flasktut;
CREATE DATABASE some_db; -- somedb is owned by flasktut
RESET SESSION AUTHORIZATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have already used localhost port server,so you can create another database in localhost port server(no need to add server in postgres ,create a db directly from that port server)

or
you can check on settings in pg_hba.conf?
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/postgresql.html

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL authentication system is managed in [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). Multiple [authentication mechanisms](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html) can be configured depending on how the connection is made, to which database and by which user.

What can be surprising coming from a MySQL background is the default configuration often in place in Linux installations: it is using `peer` authentication by default for local connections.

Here are the default values on a Debian/Ubuntu system:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

- `peer` looks for the current Linux user running `psql` (or whatever PostgreSQL client). In this case, password authentication is not used, but it relies on the OS providing the user name. This only works locally, using a Unix socket here (which is the default when you don't specify anything to `psql`).
- `md5` will ask for a password, but this is only configured for network connections in this configuration.

As a result, if I create a user and a DB as follows (logged on as `postgres`):

```
postgres@mymachine:~$ createuser -S -D -R -P myuser
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 

postgres@mymachine:~$ createdb -E UTF-8 -O myuser mydb
```

This will try to connect using a unix socket, and fail because I'm still logged on as `postgres`, not as `myuser` (which may or may not even exist on that system):

```
postgres@mymachine:~$ psql -U myuser mydb
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

(Had I been logged on as `myuser` in that Linux shell, it would have worked.)

In contrast, if I explicitly specify I want to connect via the network (albeit `127.0.0.1`), I am prompted for the password and I can log on:

```
postgres@mymachine:~$ psql -U myuser -h 127.0.0.1 mydb
Password for user myuser: 
psql (9.1.20)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=>
```

The `trust` mechanism is one that presents the most security risks, in that it does not check anything, but the connection mode on that line.

For example:

```
# This will let any local user connect to any DB via the Unix socket 
# without any authentication:
local   all             all                                     trust

# This will let any user connect to any DB via 127.0.0.1 
# without any authentication:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# And worse (DO NOT USE):
# This will let any user connect to any DB from anywhere 
# without any authentication:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

There are not many cases besides resetting a lost `postgres` (admin) password where using `trust` is justified.

---

As a side note, you say you've used this to change the password in `psql`:

```
postgres=# ALTER USER flasktut WITH PASSWORD 'zx80xb1';
ALTER ROLE
```

This works indeed, but there are a couple of side effects: the password is now likely to be logged in clear in `~/.psql_history`, and it may also have been logged on the server side (wherever its logs are sent).

Within `psql`, it is generally better to use the `\password` command:

```
postgres=# \password flasktut
Enter new password: 
Enter it again:
```

This will not leave a trace of the password in clear in the logs or history.